# ¿Cómo convertir un código Node JS a Javascript normal?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angularjs-2.0

¿Cómo puedo convertir lo siguiente, que es código hecho en *Node JS*, a *Javascript* normal?

```
new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')
```

Comment: JavaScript normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo a través de:

https://github.com/chrisdickinson/bops

No hay soporte directo para Buffer en JavaScript basado en el navegador.

La funcionalidad equivalente en el navegador es proporcionada por TypedArrays

Puedes consultarlo aquí:

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Vectores_tipados

Estas respuestas en stackoverflow en ingles te pueden ser de utilidad:

[Converting between strings and ArrayBuffers](http://Javascript%20-%20Converting%20between%20Unicode%20string%20and%20ArrayBuffer)

[Javascript - Converting between Unicode string and ArrayBuffer](http://Javascript%20-%20Converting%20between%20Unicode%20string%20and%20ArrayBuffer)

Espero que con esta información lo puedas solucionar,

Saludos

Answer (score 2):

No necesitas incluir ninguna librería, todos los navegadores modernos [soportan](http://caniuse.com/#search=btoa) nativamente codificar a `base64` utilizando [`window.btoa()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa).

Ejemplo:

```js
var client_id = 'client_id';
var client_secret = 'client_secret';

console.log(
  window.btoa(client_id + ':' + client_secret)
);
```